# Laravel Guzzle no value when accessing property when there is value

Tags: php, laravel, object

I'm trying to get the token from a third party api.

```
public function getToken()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.bar/api/oauth/']);
    $response = $client->post('token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
        ],
        'auth' => [
            'sdflsfs', //username
            'd80f8039' //password
        ]
    ]);
    return $response->getBody();
}
```

When I use return `$response->getBody()` it returns this:

```
{"access_token":"UefwLtQZJd3Bz5i5lh6ydEvAi78HZ6zqqLWXvqtZ44G3E0V","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":"resource.WRITE resource.READ"}
```

However when I do return `$response->getBody()->access_token` Laravel returns

```
BadMethodCallException
No value for access_token
```

How do I retrieve the access_token?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I needed to use json_decode() before I can access the values.